# playing embedded base 64 encoded audio in android webview

Tags: html, webview, android-webview, html5-audio

I am trying to play base64 encoded audio embedded in a HTML page from my webview.
It is playing in pc browser but not in android WebView. the html page is shown below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body><h1>HTML test  </h1><p>testing  audio</p><`enter code here`audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,,SUQzAwAAAAABdlBSSVYAAAAOAABQZWFrVmFsdWUA/38AAFBSSVYAAAARAABBdmVyYWdlTGV2ZWwAICAgI  < Base64 encoded string of mp3 file >   CAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
ICAgICAgICAgICAgDA==" />
</audio></body></html>
```

and this how I am displaying the html page

```
 mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.loadUrl(HTML_FILE_URL_FOR_WEB_VIEW_TEST);
```

But audio is not getting played in android webview. 
Is it possible to do it without using java scripts.
any help is welcomed.

Comment: please share how you solved this